# Splitting data into bins in histplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem with sns.histplot(). As far as I understand, the `bins` parameter should indicate how many of the bins should be in the plot. Here is some code to visualize the strange (at least for me) behavior.

```
    d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10 , 11 , 12, 13, 14, 15], 'col2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 , 2 , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    sns.histplot(data=df, x='col1', multiple='dodge', hue='col2', binwidth=2, bins=8)
```

[image: Example]

I have almost the same problem in my original code where I have:

```
hist = sns.histplot(data=Data, x=y_data, multiple='dodge', ax=axes[0], hue=i[2][1], binwidth=2, bins=10)
```

[image: Original histogram]

And as you can see, there is only one bin where data has its minimum and std, but it is not split into the number of bins I declared. Why is this not splitting data into the provided number of bins? How can I change code to ensure constant number of bins?

Comment: In your second plot, you should leave out `bin_width=2`,  as it makes the bars much too wide. The bars are so wide only the tallest is seen, occluding all the rest.  The width is measured in the coordinates shown on the x-axis (between 11.75 and 13.50, while your data is only between 11.6 and 12.2).

Comment: For the first part I bet you want `discrete=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the binwidth parameter. Maybe just try to delete that parameter, or set it to a smaller value (0.2 or 0.1).

Comment: Oh, I never thought of that. Deleting this parameter allows to change number of bins

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), regarding the `binwidth` parameter:

> Width of each bin, overrides `bins` but can be used with `binrange`.

So you can't specify both `bins` and `binwidth` at the same time.